# How to use Compare-and-swap for complex data structures

Tags: multithreading, compare-and-swap

Classic CaS examples deal with simple data structures where critical change is to one primitive variable. However, even linked list, for example, requires change in multiple data items. For example: head, tail, next and prev. How to deal with it?
I have in mind some "capturing" 4 pointers in 4-long memory block and putting the block into CAS routine. Is it technically available and good practice?

Comment: What about using a pointer to the complex structure and do the CaS on the complex-structure pointer? Do you consider specific architectures (eg. x86_64, Intel specific) or do you want to keep the code portable?

Comment: @JérômeRichard I don't see how it's feasible through indirect reference. Even if you capture pointer, still, referenced pointers remain out of control. Regarding architecture I mean default x86_64 but I'd like to know if other architectures give some advantage in this issue.

Comment: You can use an atomic exchanges to "lock" the pointer by setting it to null temporary but this should not be better than locks (because of read stalls). You can also work on a private partial copy and use CaS to atomically replace the data structure pointer enabling parallel reads during the modification, but it may not be applicable to all data structures. Actually, I think what you want is [hardware transactional memory](https://w.wiki/PZK). Intel & ARM provides instructions for that (ie. TSX & TME). Working atomically on multiple pointers is OK as long as they belong to the same cache line.